# How to insert credit card expiration date in insert query in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, vb.net

I need to insert expiration date of credit card into database.

But i have only date and year dropdown.There is no dropdown for month.

If i am using this way then it gives error,because without month dateformat is wrong.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExpirationDate", dobday.Value & "-" & dobyear.Value)
```

Please suggest me how i can insert this in database.

Comment: So add a month dropdown.....?

Comment: `There is no dropdown for month.` Expiration date of credit card is usually `month/year`. It doesn't contain day part. So your UI should have a drop down for Month and Year and their values should be stored in DB

Comment: What are you storing in the DB? A `datetime`? or a `varchar`? or...?

Comment: sorry there are 2 dropdowns ,month and year.so how i can insert month and year into database.

Comment: @MarcGravell  datatype of columns is datetime but here i am trying to insert  by making them string as you can see this.                       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExpirationDate", dobday.Value & "-" & dobyear.Value)

Comment: Please for the love of God... don't store credit card information in a database...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(from comments)

> datatype of columns is datetime but here i am trying to insert by making them string

Yeah, don't do that. If the datatype is `datetime`, then **construct a `DateTime`**:

```
var expiry = new DateTime(/* whatever you need here using dobday / dobyear */);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExpirationDate", expiry);
```

Comment: how i can insert only month and year in database one column.

Comment: @sikha you just said that the column is a `datetime`. Datetimes do not have a format: they are a point in time. There is no concept of only storing a month and year. You could assume the 1st of the month, or the last of the month. Presumably the latter.

Comment: i am new to programming so i don't have much knowledge...Can you please tell me is there any way so i can save (6-2012) in database column with datatype datetime.I am sorry if i am wrong.

Comment: @sikha 6-2012 ***is not a datetime***. So no, you can't store that in a `datetime` column, for the same reason that you can't store `"abc"` in an integer. The 1st of June 2012 (zero hours) is a datetime, and the 30th of June 2012 (zero hours) is a datetime. Personally, I'd say that `datetime` is not a good data type for storing this. I'd probably go for `int` and store `201206` (or possibly `char(6)` and store `'201206'`, but I'd prefer the `int`). One nice thing about year-first is that it works correctly when sorting / comparing.

Comment: i tried with char(6) its working.data is saving like this(2-2012)

Comment: @sikha I'm interested what you are going to store for october, november and december... and again: year-first. Always year first. Otherwise you cannot compare orginally. And always double-digit the month. `2012-02` might be sensible, but that is **not** `char(6)`.

Comment: its giving me erro (String or binary data would be truncated).if i tried to insert 12-2012

Comment: @sikha are you still trying to insert it into a datetime? or into a `char(6)`? because `12-2012` ***is not 6 characters***. It is 7. And again, please please please this is really important: year first. Always always year first.

Comment: yes i am trying year first now like this (2012-11). with char(6)...will it work with if i set char(7) permanently in database.?

Comment: @sikha it'll work until the year 10k... not sure you need to worry about that too much.

Comment: you are right MARC.Thanks alot to teach me this way.really thanks alot

Answer (score 3):

You have three options.

The first is to modify your database so that the expiration date is a char(4).  Then store it as MMYY.  You don't need the dash or even day part for processing.

The second option is to modify your query so that you pass the day part as "1".  So a CC that expires in December or 2012 would be 12/1/2012.  Of course, your code should drop the day when you are doing something with it.

Personally, I'd go with option three.  Don't store it at all.  There is simply zero reason to store cc details in any database.  Nearly all CC transaction providers provide much better ways of handling recurring transaction where your system doesn't have to keep that info around.  If you are working with one that doesn't, then change providers as they are way behind the times.  Otherwise you are playing with fire.

Comment: +1 for option three.  In fact it is *illegal* (at least in the US) in some cases to store Credit Card information.

Comment: I had to replace 4 credit / debit cards multiple times last year because various morons at companies like Target can't secure their stuff.  I can't stress how much of a PITA this was and how totally PO'd I am at companies / developers that store this info.

Comment: @EvanL from the PCI compliance specs: "If required for business purposes, the cardholder’s name, PAN, expiration date, and service code may be stored as long as they are protected in accordance with PCI DSS requirements." - however, I would be **greatly** concerned if this is being implemented by an entry-level developer (https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/pdfs/pci_fs_data_storage.pdf)

Comment: @MarcGravell Absolutely, Based on the question I fear that may be the case.  As Chris Lively pointed out, there are so many other ways to retrieve this information that it just seems like the OP should explore other avenues.